# How to get an exact string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a Substring from a string.

Here is the slice from the code:

```
var inputString = '[app:abcd][class:sample][instance:value:wq-23333:site-
1.1.1.1:jhk-1][descr:endss.]'
```

I want to get the value after instance: to the next closing of square bracket.

So the output should be :

```
var outputString = 'value:wq-23333:site-1.1.1.1:jhk-1'
```

Note : The position where the string instance comes is not fixed and the above is a String not an Array and I am writing code in javascript.

Comment: There is not a single String value in that piece of code...

Comment: `inputString.split('instance')[1].split(']')[0]`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do have a string and just forgot to add quotes you could use a regexp `/\[instance\:([^\]]+)\]/` that looks for `[instance:` part and captures everything until next closing bracket.

```js
var inputString = "[app:abcd][class:sample][instance:value:wq-23333:site-1.1.1.1:jhk-1][descr:endss.]"

console.log(/\[instance\:([^\]]+)\]/.exec(inputString)[1])
```